# How to set two block on the same line by middle?

Tags: html, css

I need that content of first block will be floated to left and content of right block to right side:

```html
<div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
</div>
```

I need to get this:

```
    _______________
    A_____________B
```

But now I get:

```
___________________
A               
                  B
__________________
```

Comment: You need to reverse the order of the elements for that to work this way ...

Comment: `But now I get:` - Where is the CSS that gives you that? Can you add it to your snippet please so we can see what you did? Also, do you want them simply floated left and right or do you want to auto fill each 50% of the page or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved by own simple solution:

CSS:

```
.parent { display: table; width: 100%;}
.children { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="children"></div>
   <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using flexbox

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 25%;
  border-top: thin solid darkgray;
  border-bottom: thin solid darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) or this custom code

```
<style>
    .div_lg {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .div_md {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
<div class="div_lg">
    <div class="div_md">A</div>
    <div class="div_md">B</div>
</div>
```

[See Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7q5ttot/)

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.parent {
  display:flex;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid
}

.parent div:first-of-type {
 width: 50%;
}

.parent div:last-of-type {
  width: 50%;
 float:right;
 display:block;
 text-align: right;
}
```

---

And here the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/osvdpr1y/

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a css property to both the div `display: inline-block` . See the below code.

```html
<style>
  .a{
     width: 200px;
     background: red;
    }
  .b{
     width: 200px;
     background: blue;
    }
  .a, .b {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
   }
</style>

<!--HTML-->
<div>
   <div class="a">A</div>
   <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can align them both on the same line like this.

```
<div class="sameLine">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
</div>

.sameLine div {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
  <div style="float:left;display:block;max-width:50%;border:1px solid red;">Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  <div style="float:right;display:block;max-width:50%; border:1px solid red;">Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
</div>
```